# Find out the hash of a string

Tags: hash

I would like to know what kind of hash it is:

String(without hash): 123123

String(with hash): 68944173

I can not find anywhere information what kind of hash it is.

Comment: That's almost *impossible* to say.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude maybe you can know it from the type: integer and lenght: 9 chars?